# sbt: publish generated sources

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a project where part of the sources are generated (`sourceGenerators in Compile`). I noticed that (in most scenarios reasonably) these sources are not published with `publishLocal` or `publishSigned`. In this case this is unfortunate because when you use this project/library as a dependency, you cannot look up the sources, for example in IntelliJ, even if the other sources of the project have been downloaded.

Can I configure sbt's publishing settings to include the generated sources in the Maven `-sources.jar`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
mappings in (Compile,packageSrc) := (managedSources in Compile).value map (s => (s,s.getName)),
```

Comment: Would this be `++=` instead of `:=` so that the regular sources are not dropped?

Comment: Yes, ++= would be correct. My particular usage of this is with only generated sources and no regular sources, thus :=

Comment: Also, you'll need to set the path correctly instead of `s.getName` if there are collisions

Answer (score 12):

So, just to be complete, this was my solution based on @pfn's answer:

```
mappings in (Compile, packageSrc) ++= {
  val base  = (sourceManaged  in Compile).value
  val files = (managedSources in Compile).value
  files.map { f => (f, f.relativeTo(base).get.getPath) }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like @0__'s answer, but ported to the 'new' sbt syntax, i.e. without deprecation warnings.

```
Compile/packageSrc/mappings ++= {
  val base  = (Compile/sourceManaged).value
  val files = (Compile/managedSources).value
  files.map(f => (f, f.relativeTo(base).get.getPath))
}
```